# Use of %? in unix

Tags: unix

I am new to unix, can someone please tell me the purpose of '%?' in below command:

```
-bash-3.2$ sample=test123
-bash-3.2$ sample=${sample%?}
-bash-3.2$ echo $sample
test12
```

I can see that it is removing the last character but can I remove as many characters as I want, for example 3 charactes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pattern matching operator, meaning "if the pattern matches the end of the variable's value, delete the shortest part that matches and return the rest". Since `?` matches "any single character", the last character will be removed.

So if you want to remove three characters, you need to replace the `?` with an expression that matches three characters instead of just one.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is bash parameter substitution operators which remove from shortest rear

```
${var%pattern}
```

`?` means any single character

Answer (score 1):

First:
man 1 bash

Syntax: ${varname%word} where word is a "matching suffix pattern", so you can:

*remove only "123":*

```
echo ${sample%123}
test
```

*remove any 3 characters:*

```
echo ${sample%???}
test
```

etc

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew for the quick response.